# Decoding unknown language

Tags: undeciphered-writing

When I was at school they told the Rosetta Stone was useful to decode hieroglyphics, because it had the same text in a known and in an unknown language (at least that's what I remember).

And, generally, reading around it seems this is the usual method to decode unknown languages.

Even seatching in the Internet it seems the AI helps but still it needs some comparison.

So, I want to ask: is that the sole way? What if there's no text in a known language to compare? Is it possible still decode a language without anything else? No same text in a known laguage, no cultural context, no drawings attached, nothing, only the symbols.

If there are ways to do it, how are they called?

Comment: Generally, they don't. See, for example, Linear A, or the Indus script.